# Struct static vars under inheritance

Tags: swift

how the ambiguity can be resolved in this case provided that I can't change the name `Static` and the name `SOMECONST` for each class (to keep a consistent convention across the API classes)

it might or might not work in playgrounds but the error `AMBIGUOUS USE OF SOMECONST` appears during compilation in Xcode.

If it's not possible then I'm going to revert to getters, any person got an idea if Apple will implement `static` for classes or it's only designed for `struct` and `enum`???

```
public class A {

    public struct Static {
        public static let SOMECONST = 1
    }

    init(val: Int) {
        println(val)
    }
}

public class B: A {

    public struct Static {
        public static let SOMECONST = 2
    }

    init() {
        super.init(val: B.Static.SOMECONST)
    }

}

B()
```

Comment: js it necessary that class B inherit class A?

Comment: yes, if it's not possible I'm going to revert to getter instead, Any idea if apple is really going to implement static for class or it's only for structs and enums

Comment: Using accessors is a better idea, otherwise you've just leaked your abstraction.

Comment: sorry, leaked your abstraction means?

Comment: Since both `Static` and `SOMECONST` are static members... Can't you declare `SOMECONST` as a static property of your **class**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program (unsurprisingly) can't compile because it found two candidates for the `SOMECONST` symbol:

```
error: ambiguous use of 'SOMECONST'
    super.init(val: B.Static.SOMECONST)
                      ^
note: found this candidate
    static let SOMECONST = 2
               ^
note: found this candidate
    static let SOMECONST = 1
               ^
```

Using nested types for storing constants like this is generally a bad idea, because nested types can't be overriden by subclasses. You should declare the constants directly as part of your class.

Now, ideally you would do something like this:

```
class A {
    class let SOMECONST = 1
}

class B: A {
    override class let SOMECONST = 2
}
```

But, unfortunately, this is not supported by the current Swift compiler. The only way you can override a class (static) variable is to make it computable:

```
class A {
    class var SOMECONST: Int {
        return 1
    }
}

class B: A {
    override class var SOMECONST: Int {
        return 2
    }
}
```

That's a little bit uglier, but it works. You can now create your `B`'s initializer:

```
init() {
    super.init(val: B.SOMECONST) // prints "2"
}
```

Comment: Any idea if Apple is gonna really implement class vars/let like `class let SOMECONST = 1`